# Async controller rendering data

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asynchronous, model-view-controller

I used to implement **Sync** actions in web api applications, and to get data asynchronously I used **AJAX** in the client part to get datas from api actions.

Then I read about `async controller` , I need to know the lifecycle to render a page

For example :

```
 public async Task<ActionResult> PWGasync()
    {
        ViewBag.SyncType = "Asynchronous";
        var widgetService = new WidgetService();
        var prodService = new ProductService();
        var gizmoService = new GizmoService();

        var widgetTask = widgetService.GetWidgetsAsync(); 
         await Task.Run(widgetTask);

        var pwgVM = new ProdGizWidgetVM( widgetTask.Result  );

        return View("PWG", pwgVM);
    }
```

did the view will be rendred first and then the data will be displayed?

Comment: No. The view will be rendered after all tasks are completed so that all results needed for rendering are available.

Comment: [Lifecycle of an ASP.NET MVC 5 Application](https://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/getting-started/lifecycle-of-an-aspnet-mvc-5-application)

Comment: @AndriyTolstoy what is the difference then between async and sync action ?

Comment: In this example the advantage is that all three tasks will be executed parallel each in its own thread and not one after another, so that the entire result needed for rendering could be retrieved faster.

Comment: @AndriyTolstoy yes in this example you are right. But generally parallelism is not async it is two different concepts. I mean if no parallelism exists (for exemple i'm waiting  for only a task). what is the benefits of async action if the page is still not rendred until the task will be finished

Comment: Using an async will release an IIS thread, so that it can handle another incoming request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> did the view will be rendred first and then the data will be displayed?

No. `async` does not change the HTTP protocol. There is still one request and one response.

> what is the difference then between async and sync action ?

`async` actions allow the request thread to return to the thread pool while the `await` operation is in progress. This makes better use of the thread pool, which in turn allows much better scalability of the web service.

Comment: thanks, you mentionned "which in turn allows much better scalability of the web service" in the example the action will return a view not datas so I don't see any need for using async action .

Comment: @LamloumiAfif: What the action returns is immaterial. `async` is about freeing up threads.